# Proper response to user abusing "flag as duplicate"

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, abuse

My [4 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/pandas-test-if-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list?noredirect=1#comment87266920_26577516) was flagged as a duplicate of this [4 month old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541444/pandas-filtering-for-multiple-substrings-in-series) by the same user who posted that question. My question has more upvotes on both the question and the answer, and is (obviously) significantly older. I also happen to think they aren't even the same question--the other question is a much more specific case that most users wouldn't need. It seems to me like a silly attempt by that user to drive more traffic to their own question.

I can't flag the flag itself for review, so what's the proper response to these sorts of cases? Just flag for reopening? Try to get a moderator involved?

Comment: 1. This should probably better asked at [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) 2. Why do you premise _abusive_ behavior here exactly?

Comment: Whoops, I guess I thought I was there... should I delete this question and re-ask it there? 2 It seemed like either poor investigation or abuse to me, but I don't have tools to investigate other questions that user has closed (AFAIK) to see if there's a pattern. So I figured the equivalent of a flag for abuse would turf it to someone who had those investigative powers. But you're right, I probably should have titled it "possible abuse"

Comment: _"should I delete this question and re-ask it there?"_ Probably yes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This question is on-topic here, as it can be generalized.

Comment: @Sonic I agree that this can be generalized, but the OP refers to a very specific example from SO, so that should be discussed there in 1st place, with all the necessary background wisdom.

Comment: You need to visit your "local" meta, ask (humbly) whether the newer answers would apply to your older question. I would also mention the fact that your question has attracted 25,720 times in less than four years while the much newer question in three months has been visited only 579 times. Do the sums as to the average no. of views per month and I think you have a strong case. Disclaimer: I did not understand what the two questions were about.

Comment: @Mari-LouA _" I did not understand what the two questions were about."_ That's my point.

Comment: And the author of the newer question has also marked these two questions as duplicates: 1.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118786/performance-of-pandas-string-contains-for-column?noredirect=1&lq=1 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428785/checkinf-if-words-in-a-list-exists-in-rows-of-text-in-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1 See if other questions have also been earmarked as duplicates. It seems the new author  must have a golden hammer in the relevant tag(s). @πάνταῥεῖ I was composing my commment when you posted yours, I've just given some advice on what to say on SO meta.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I didn't really want to argue and was the one (ATM) upvoting your comment. And as your research shows, that there might be an abuse regarding the user's mjölnir powers (the golden hammer), better asked at MSO in 1st place yet.

Comment: Assuming there are no relevant deleted comments on either question: was it really necessary to frame this as an accusation and then bring it all the way to Meta.SE right at the outset? It seems likely that a comment pinging the close voter explaining why you think your question isn't a duplicate would have been enough to defuse the situation and bring forth an amicable resolution.

Comment: [The MSO question about this situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367459/2751851), asked by the close voter.

Answer (score 9):

I've reopened the question as it was clearly a conflict of interest to use the gold badge close privilege to close other questions as duplicates **of their own, new question**.

Using the privilege to close questions to point to one **you have answered** is perfectly fine.

In future a flag is probably your best recourse, though it might take a little while to get processed.

Comment: Note: this has been brought up in [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367459/how-to-use-gold-dupehammer-without-abuse)

Comment: @SurajRao And the long debate that generated there _clearly_ states that it was not _"clearly"_ an abuse of close privilege, as ChrisF claims. Maybe it was an abuse, maybe it wasn't, the debate is still going, so it was not "clear", one way or the other.

Comment: @xDaizu using the gold tag badge privilege to close other questions as duplicates **of your own question** is a conflict of interest. I probably went too far to say it was an abuse